# Access 2010 application, SQL Server 2008R2 back-end, throwing error "Could not find field"

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

An Access form (called FFF, let us say) is linked to a SQL Server table via a DSN-less connection. 
Everything works OK.
There is a field on the form called (for the sake of argument) XXX. 
The bound control (i.e. the SS data name) is also called XXX.
Usually, it shows data correctly, and allows updates.

Occasionally, when XXX is referred to in VBA code behind the form, such as 
   "IF XXX > somevalue THEN ..."
an Access error occurs, with the number -2147352567 and the description "Could not find field."

It doesn't name the field that can't be found, but the error line is the line mentioned above, which refers only to the field XXX.

I have tried extending the field reference by using Me.XXX, or Forms!FFF!XXX, but the problem remains.

The client PC is running MS Access 2010 runtime.
There are no Access (Jet) tables involved.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this error, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access can occasionally get confused when a Control on a form has the same name as the Record Source field (column) to which it is bound. This can sometimes lead to strange behaviour similar to what you've described.

For example when we drag and drop the field `LastName` onto a form we get a text box whose `.Name` is "LastName". Under those circumstances VBA code referring to `Me.LastName` is actually ambuguous: Are we referring to the *field* [LastName] in the Row Source, or are we referring to the *control* on the form with the same name? In many cases it doesn't matter, but sometimes it does.

The solution is to rename the control. A common convention is to add a prefix to the control name based on the type of control: `txtLastName` for a text box, `cbxCategory` for a combo box, etc.. That clears up the ambiguity because `Me.LastName` is the *field*, and `Me.txtLastName` is the *control*.

Comment: Ambuguous gave me pause, but then I concluded you meant ambiguity leads to bugs.  Brilliant!

Comment: Thanks for that, Gord - I only just noticed you had answered. The thing that confuses me is, this only happens occasionally - usually no error is thrown. Why would Access get it right most of the time. but sometimes not?